# Jquery Hide/Show logo on page scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't get my function to run correctly. At a certain height its supposed to animate the logo onto the page. However on my if statement when i scroll up it won't return to being hidden off the page

Here is my function.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) {
  //$('#logo').show( 'slow' );
  //$("#logo").css('left', function(){ return $(this).offset().left; })
  //.animate({"left":"30"}, "slow");
  $("#logo").animate({left: "30"});
}
else {
  $("#logo").animate({left: "0"});
}
```

Here is my CSS for #logo

```
#logo {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -493px;
}
```

Comment: can you add jsfiddle here

Comment: Could you add a code snippet/JSFiddle/CodePen that reproduces the problem? If you do, we can help you much more easily...

Answer (score 0):

this can be approached different ways, you can simply add or remove class depending the height the page is scrolled and style the width, visibility or left position with css, or you can edit this attributes using jquery `css()` function.

But if you want to use `animate()` this can help you:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) {
    $("#logo").animate({width: 0}, 20);
  }
  else {
    $("#logo").animate({width: 50}, 20);
  }
 });
```

in your style remove de `left` attribute and set the `position: fixed`

I recommend to do this with classes and css